# Change IP address of Solace VMR Community Edition on ESXi 6.5

Tags: solace

I have installed Solace VMR 8.1.0 Community Edition on ESXi 6.5.  I have a few IP addresses provided by our network engineer to be used for VMs on this ESXi server.  May I know how I can change the IP address of the Solace VMR?  The [online guide](http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Starting-VMRs-for-the-First-Time/Setting-Up-a-VMR-with-ESXi.htm#Configur) does not mention this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to login via the sysadmin user to configure a static IP address for the interface.

Please refer to [Configuring Interfaces With Static IP Addresses](http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Configuring-Interfaces-on-VMR-Hosts.htm) on Solace's documentation page for the exact steps to do so.

Comment: Thank you, Russell.  It is working now after following the steps using sysadmin account with sudo command (e.g. sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0).